# Getting the class name of an object in strategy design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

i am trying to understand the design pattern, and i need to know 
how can i retrieve the name of the class in the implemented interface class, as 
follow:

```
public interface Flys {

   String fly();

}

// Class used if the Animal can fly

class ItFlys implements Flys{

    public String fly() {

        return getClass().getName()+" is Flying High"; //not working...gives me the ItFlys class name not Dog class name

    }

}

//Class used if the Animal can't fly

class CantFly implements Flys{

    public String fly() {

        return "I can't fly";

    }

}
```

Code from: http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/08/strategy-design-pattern-tutorial/
Thanks

Comment: Where is your `Dog` class? — Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JonnyHenly  I think the link is usefull (wouldn t be much clearer if i would paste 10 classes here) and i presented a very clear problem.If you would know some design patterns, you wouldn't need the link  ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you are facing is that neither `Dog` nor `Bird` *implements* `Flys` interface. Instead, each class *contains* an implementation. Since `ItFlys` does not know, by design, inside what class it is contained, calling `fly()` on it has no way of detecting the class outside it.

You can fix the problem by changing the `fly` method to take `Object` representing the "owner", and calling `getName` on owner's class:

```
public interface Flys {
   String fly(Object owner);
}

// Class used if the Animal can fly
class ItFlys implements Flys{
    public String fly(Object owner) {
        return owner.getClass().getName()+" is Flying High";
    }
}
```

Now `Dog` needs to provide its own implementation of `fly()` method that forwards the call to its `flyingType`:

```
public String fly() {
    flyingType.fly(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is encapsulated in the `ItFlys class` so it gets the name of its encompassing class.

```
return getClass().getName()+" is Flying High";
```

If an instance of an object is available, then the simplest way to get its Class is to invoke `Object.getClass()`. Of course, this only works for reference types which all inherit Object. Assuming your `Dog.java` inherits `Object` then you would want the following

```
return new Dog().getClass().getSimpleName() + " is Flying High";
```

edit: `getName()` will include the package name in the returned `String`